# How to add a line in pdf like <hr/> tag in html

Tags: itext

I need a line which is like a

---

tag in html page by using the pdf generation from iTextSharp.dll

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could [draw Shapes and Graphics](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/88/iTextSharp-Drawing-shapes-and-Graphics) with iTextSharp.

Answer (score 1):

I found this online, haven't tested but will later if it doesn't work for you.

```
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, out);
PdfContentByte cb = writer.getDirectContent();

cb.setLineWidth(2.0f);   // Make a bit thicker than 1.0 default
cb.setGrayStroke(0.95f); // 1 = black, 0 = white
float x = 72f;
float 7 = 72f;
cb.moveTo(x,         y);
cb.lineTo(x + 72f*6, y);
cb.stroke();
```

Comment: how can we do the line generation in the pdf in the .htm file?

Comment: FYI: SetGrayStroke seems to actually be 0 = black, 1 = white.

Answer (score 1):

**Since, iTextSharp do have limitations in understanding few HTML styles/tags and give errors on including `<hr />` tag in html while parsing.**

**The solution to this is a little workaround and use graphics:**

- You need to create a new class which extends the `HTMLWorker` class and overrides the `StartElement` method which gives us event on starting of every html element.

  ```
  public class HTMLWorkerExtended : HTMLWorker
  {
  LineSeparator line = new LineSeparator(4f, 100f, BaseColor.BLACK, Element.ALIGN_CENTER, -1);
  public HTMLWorkerExtended(IDocListener document): base(document)
  {

  }
  public override void StartElement(string tag, IDictionary<string, string> str)
  {
      if (tag.Equals("hrline"))
          document.Add(new Chunk(line));
      else
          base.StartElement(tag, str);
  }
  ```

  }
- In your html, add `<hrline />` tag, wherever you want a page break.
- Now use `HTMLWorkerExtended` class' object to parse the html.

  ```
              using (TextReader htmlViewReader = new StringReader(htmlText))
              {
                  using (var htmlWorker = new HTMLWorkerExtended(pdfDocument))
                  {
                      htmlWorker.Open();
                      htmlWorker.Parse(htmlViewReader);
                  }
              }
  ```